# MVC BeginForm not reaching Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a Login-Form which should use my LoginControler. If I post my form I get a "The resource can not be found." Error.

I researched, but in my opinion the code should working like this. Maybe i have some routing problem? But actually i didn't do any configuration on my MVC project. It's the default MVC 5 project.

This is my Controller:

```
public class LoginController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login(UserLoginModel m)
    {


        return View();
    }
}
```

This is the Form:

```
@using cxWeb.Controllers
@model cxWeb.Models.UserLoginModel


@using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "LoginController", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "LoginForm", @enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <div class="modal-body">
        <fieldset>
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.nickname, new { @class = "form-control-form", @placeholder = "Nickname", @tabindex = "1" })
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.PasswordFor(model => model.password, new { @class = "form-control-form", @placeholder = "Password", @tabindex = "2" })
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <label>
                            <input type="checkbox"> Keep login
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6 text-left">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 text-right">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#SignUpModal">Sign up</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ForgotPasswordModal">Forgot password</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

And this is my model:

```
public class UserLoginModel
{
    [Required]
    public string nickname { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string password { get; set; }
}
```

This is my Project:

[image: My project]

**After post I will be redirect to this URL:**

http://localhost:1853/LoginController/Login

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks for reading

Comment: You need to remove `Controller` keyword from `@using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "LoginController",....{}` . It should be `@using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Login",..{}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this. Change LoginController to just Login.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Login", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "LoginForm", @enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
```

Comment: Hey, now i get this error: The "Login" view or the corresponding template was not found, or none of the view modules supported the searched locations. The following locations have been searched:~/Views/Login/Login.aspx
~/Views/Login/Login.ascx
~/Views/Shared/Login.aspx
~/Views/Shared/Login.ascx
~/Views/Login/Login.cshtml
~/Views/Login/Login.vbhtml
~/Views/Shared/Login.cshtml
~/Views/Shared/Login.vbhtml

Comment: Since you are posting to LoginController you have to return a valid action that has a view. Can i see your login action on your LoginController?

Comment: The LoginController Code i posted above is the whole
 Controller. I just return View(). I have not done anything yet. Now i tried to return to the TopEvents Page and it works. So i guess it's working now? Or do i have to do anything else? :)